# itext 7 text extraction from PDF file outputs unreadable text

Tags: c#, pdf, fonts, itext

itext generates unreadable text when I try to extract the text from the attached PDF.

The font used in the PDF is `True type` (cid) with Identity-H encoding

`{<< / BaseFont / GCMURL + SegoeUI / DescendantFonts [13 0 R] / Encoding / Identity-H / Subtype / Type0 / Type / Font >>}`

```
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser;
using System.Diagnostics;
using iText.Kernel.Font;

            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(@"C:\Users\Myfile-_.pdf");
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);

            for (int page = 1; page <= pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); page++)
            {
                PdfPage pagina = pdfDoc.GetPage(page);
                PdfDictionary fontResources = pagina.GetResources().GetResource(PdfName.Font);

                foreach (PdfObject font in fontResources.Values(true))
                {

                    if (font is PdfDictionary)
                        fontResources.Put(PdfName.Encoding, PdfName.IdentityH);
                }

                ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                string pageContent = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDoc.GetPage(page), strategy);

                Debug.WriteLine("pageContent : " + pageContent);
            }
            pdfDoc.Close();
            pdfReader.Close();
```

Any suggestions as to what I might have missed?
PDF is available here: https://files.fm/u/r4ejybyp8

Comment: Trying to copy&paste from that pdf in Adobe Reader also results in garbage. Usually you cannot expect iText to extract text better than Adobe Reader copy&paste. Your file simply doesn't contain the information for easy text extraction.

Comment: copying and pasting text with acrobat reader does not work, if I use pdfxchange I can export the readable text,
is there a way to extract the text anyway, or is there a working library in core c#?

Comment: iText text extraction and Adobe Reader copy&paste implement the algorithm for text extraction described in the PDF specification. Your PDF is made to have its text not extractable by that algorithm. So implicitly calling iText non-working is a bit harsh as you're looking for a feature beyond the specification. That being said, you might have more success with PDF Clown, it explicitly looks for the mapping to Unicode at a different place than the spec describes. As far as I know, though, that project is abandoned.